# Cannot authenticate CloudKit JS using apiTokenAuth only without serverToServerKeyAuth

Tags: node.js, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services, cloudkit-js

I am building a web in Node that uses data stored in iCloud using CloudKit on a Public Database. To query the data I have created an `apiToken` and a `serverToServerKey`. For the first one I have a string but for the server to server authentication I've got a `pem` file which contains a private key. To configure CloudKit I am doing the following:

```
CloudKit.configure({
                services: {
                fetch: fetch
            },
            containers: [{
                containerIdentifier: 'iCloud.com.myName.Container',
                environment: "production",
                apiTokenAuth: {
                    apiToken: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    persist: true
                },
                serverToServerKeyAuth: {
                    keyID: serverKey,
                    privateKeyFile: "./private_key.pem"
                }
            }]
        });

var container = CloudKit.getDefaultContainer();

        container.setUpAuth().then(function(userIdentity) {
            if(userIdentity) {
                publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase;
                console.log("[OK] Logged in...");
                resolve(userIdentity)
            } 
        });
```

This obviously doesn't generate any problems and I can query the container for the data and my web app works without a problem locally.

The previous snippet is located in my `index.js` file and when I get the data from iCloud y pass it to my HTML file and I render it using EJS.

Now I am moving this to production and I have some questions and problems. As far as I know I cannot move the `.pem` file to the server because it contains a private key but now it's in the backend so I don't know if it's going to be publicly available.

Is there a possibility of authenticate the users that use my web app with only the `apiToken`. The users will only have to read data not modify or create so I won't need to identify them.

Am I asking something impossible or anyone has done it? I haven't found any information regarding this. When I try to authenticate the users using the previous code snippet using only the `apiTokenAuth` and deleting the `serverToServerKeyAuth` I get an `AUTHENTICATION_ERROR`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, ended up creating an API so the users access the API and it contacts CloudKit

Comment: So does your API use the server-to-server authentication then?